# jQuery Autocomplete syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I haven't had a lot of experience with jQuery but below is Autocomplete code that is successfully bolding the search characters in the search result dropdown rows:

```
.autocomplete({
      delay: 500,
      minLength: 0,

      source: function(request, response) {
        // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
        var list = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, extractLast(request.term));
        if (request.term) {
          regex = new RegExp('(' + extractLast(request.term) + ')', 'gi');
          list = list.map(function(item) {
            return {
              label: item.label.replace(regex, '<b>$1</b>'),
              value: item.value
            }
          })
        }
        response(list);
      },
```

I'm now trying to switch the source to an AJAX lookup. Can anyone let me know what the edit would be to the following AJAX code to get bold text characters like the first code example does?

```
 .autocomplete({
      delay: 500,
      minLength: 0,

      source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'default.aspx/fGetCityLookupData',
                    data: "{'strSearchText': '" + extractLast(request.term) + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.split('|')[1],
                                value: item.split('|')[0]
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
```

TIA
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered at another forum here: http://forums.asp.net/p/2092693/6042551.aspx?p=True&t=635965068036236809